# Uploading AWS Lambda Function Failure from Visual Studio 2019

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am new to AWS and Lambda. When I try to publish my Lambda from Visual Studio by using the "Publish to AWS Lambda" option, I get this error:

> Error creating IAM Role: User: arn:aws:iam::585066325803:user/MyLambda is not authorized to perform: iam:CreateRole on resource:   arn:aws:iam::585066325803:role/lambda_exec_MyFunction

[Permissions policies I added for the IAM user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHDEW.png)

I just tried different policies and added them. Do I need to do anything more than that? I thought publishing a test lambda would be easy. Please advice.

[Roles displayed for the profile](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSOrL.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `iam:PassRole` permission to the `user/MyLambda`.

You can add such policy as an [inline policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/access_policies_managed-vs-inline.html#inline-policies). An example of the policy is as follows:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "iam:PassRole",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marcin. I used the Inline policy editor and that worked. I had to add few other permissions like "list*" to see the list. Thanks.